# How oome I can't get data intent from listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I can't get data from list view. I use an XML parser. This is my code in list view. 
If I intend my list view to new activity, only show layout blank. not message in logcat.

```
/**
**/


list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
        // getting values from selected ListItem
        String headline = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
        String date = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date)).getText().toString();

        //Map<String, String> myValueMap = songList.get(position);

        // Starting new intent
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
        in.putExtra(KEY_HEADLINE, headline);
        in.putExtra(KEY_ARTICLEDATE, date);
        startActivity(in);

    }
});
```

and this is my code SingleMenuItemActivity

```
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_HEADLINE = "Headline";
static final String KEY_ARTICLEDATE = "ArticleDate";
static final String KEY_BODY = "Body";
static final String KEY_IMAGEURL = "ImageURL";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webnews);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get XML values from previous intent
    String headline = in.getStringExtra(KEY_HEADLINE);
    String date = in.getStringExtra(KEY_ARTICLEDATE);


    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblHeadline = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    TextView lblArticleDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView02);


    lblHeadline.setText(headline);
    lblArticleDate.setText(date);
    lblBody.setText(Body);
}
```

Comment: do the keys match?? and you do not send body

Comment: Are you getting some value in `headline` and `date`?

Comment: what is the value of Body and where it is declared ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you left out body.

```
    String Body = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.body)).getText().toString();
    in.putExtra(KEY_BODY, body);

    .....

    String date = in.getStringExtra(KEY_ARTICLEDATE); 
    TextView lblBody= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView03);
    lblBody.setText(Body);
```

Answer (score 0):

The key of `putExtra` is case sensitive, make sure for the below are same for both activity. You are getting null values without any error for this, as [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29) says-

```
static final String KEY_HEADLINE = "Headline";
static final String KEY_ARTICLEDATE = "ArticleDate";
static final String KEY_BODY = "Body";
static final String KEY_IMAGEURL = "ImageURL";
```

and also if you have `KEY_BODY` to pass from calling activity then pass it via intent and access it from the intent over here.